# When Customer Community users create a record, a query is used to retrieve an internal user using Id, but no records are returned?

Tags: soql, customer-community

A customer community user, when creating a case, will select an internal user using a lookup field. But in that lookup field, only Admin users are coming when searched, no other internal users appear.
So I have written a trigger on Case object to populate this field. Now when I am trying to query the internal user based on Id (I know I could have put the Id in the lookup directly, but I am querying because I need some field values also), the query is not returning any records, although that user is active. Is this the case, that triggers are affected by the Users who trigger them and so, as triggered by external user, cannot query internal users? Is there any way to circumvent this, like maybe changing the Owner?

Comment: Is your class declared with the 'with sharing' or 'without sharing' keywords?

Comment: I am using a trigger handler class without sharing.